# How to resolve a inputfile rerender problem?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, rerender

I have a VF page to create the cases and to insert the attachments to case.On Changing the picklist values i have to rerender the entire page to enter new values. But I have a inputfile tag in the VF page which doesn't support rerender. How to resolve it?

Comment: Show some VF code please. Why do you need to rerender the entire page ? Try rerendering outputpanels with only the elements that need to be rerendered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rerendering is not supported when you have an apex:inputFile component.  There's no workaround, as the platform simply will not allow it.  The best you can do is to move the apex:inputFile into an apex:iframe which will leave the rest of the "page" alone.

BTW If you are looking to rerender the entire page, that sounds the same as a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with using multiple `<apex:form>` tags, one for the `<apex:inputFile>` and one for the other elements.  I know the docs say it all gets resolved to one `<apex:form>` but it allowed me to rerender a page with a file input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for `apex:actionRegion` from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm)